# css: bootstrap drop menu right aligned icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add icons to standard bootstrap drop menu.
Icons on left are fine but I am adding secondary icons and I want those icons to float:right and aligned in single line.

**Objective:** I want secondary icons to be aligned on right side as primary ones are on left

Here is how I am adding a secondary icon , class "sec"

```
<li>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>
     SomeText
  <i class="sec fa fa-user"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ydmnf0wt/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="test" class="col-md-4">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn blue dropdown-toggle">
                Dropdown <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </button>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Action ActionActionActio 
                    <i class="sec fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>View  
                    <i class="sec fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Custom view 2  
                    <i class="sec fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Custom view 21  
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Custom view 43  
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a > i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu  i.sec
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: 300;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify CSS like this:

```
body {
    background-color : white !important;
}
@import url(netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.min.css);

.dropdown-menu{
    width:250px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    margin-right: 5px;
    height:30px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a > i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a > i.sec
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: 300;
    height: auto;
    float:right; 
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a > i.first
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: 300;
    height: auto;
    float:left; 
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a > .text
{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also modify each menu like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="first fa fa-save"></i>
        <span class="text">Action ActionActionActio</span>
        <i class="sec fa fa-user"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

**[Check This JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ydmnf0wt/12/)**

Comment: I'm checking with Chrome and working fine, but after you are comment check with FF and your right, maybe update my answer for firefox too.

Comment: wait there is still catch. Your solution has made my menu now width dependent. It was not before. How to fix that ?  width:250px; , it is not desirable.

Comment: menu should stretch as long as text goes .. in bootstrap .dropdown-menu doesn't have width. I want to leave it as that.